# Pandas merge_asof on multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, array-merge

The two dfs come from data of different frequencies.

```
df1 :

    INNER_CODE  TRADEDATE   CLOSE_PRICE  
0   101000038   2020/12/14  1.2 
1   101000187   2020/12/14  2.3

df2 :
    INNER_CODE  CHANGEDATE  TOT_NUMS
0   101000038   2019/11/1   100
1   101000038   2020/12/1   110
2   101000038   2020/12/15  120
3   101000187   2019/11/1   200
4   101000187   2020/11/1   210
5   101000187   2020/12/18  220
```

I wanna merge them on `df1.INNER_CODE=df2.INNER_CODE` and `df2.CHANGEDATE` is before and closest to `df1.TRADEDATE`.

```
My goal result is
    INNER_CODE  TRADEDATE   CLOSE_PRICE TOT_NUMS
0   101000038   2020/12/14  1.2        110
1   101000187   2020/12/14  2.3        210
```

I need to achieve through pandas, not through “sql outer apply”.I thought of an alternative method, implemented by `df1.apply(func)`, but it consumes memory and is too inefficient. Can it be achieved by pandas similar to `merge_asof`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. `pd.merge_asof` can solve my problem perfectly.The `df1` and `df2` need to be sorted according to TRADEDATE and CHANGEDATE in advance.

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,by='INNER_CODE',left_on='TRADEDATE',right_on='CHANGEDATE')
   INNER_CODE  TRADEDATE  CLOSE_PRICE CHANGEDATE  TOT_NUMS
0   101000038 2020-12-14          1.2 2020-12-01       110
1   101000187 2020-12-14          2.3 2020-11-01       210
```